# Android - mutli select query with Jsoup library

Tags: android, jsoup

I am working in project need to analysis web site and extract all input to fill in some way ,  I am using Jsoup library it work fine with one query but with mutli query it give wrong behavior

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements inputs = doc.select("input[type=text]");
            //Elements password = doc.select("input[type=password]");
            //Elements emails = doc.select("input[type=email]");
            for (Element ele : inputs) {
                listID.add(ele.attr("id"));
            }
```

my question how can I make mutli query with same order it appear in web page 
if we have web site has two input one with type text other with type text , how can I select both and save order

```
<input name="username" id="login-username" class="login-input pure-u-1 " maxlength="96" tabindex="1" aria-required="true" value="" placeholder="عنوان البريد الإلكتروني" title="عنوان البريد الإلكتروني" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" autofocus="" type="text">

<input name="passwd" id="login-passwd" class="login-input  pure-u-1" maxlength="64" tabindex="2" aria-required="true" placeholder="كلمة السر" title="كلمة السر" autocorrect="off" type="password">
```

Comment: You cant show full xml code?

Comment: why you think xml code will help us in our problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not actually sure if this is really what you want, you could do this to select all the elements you listed:

```
Elements inputs = doc.select("input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email]");
```

Which will select all of the `input` elements matching one of those types.

Alternatively, even simpler, you can use this to select all `input` elements:

```
doc.select("input");
```

Also check out [Jsoup's javadoc for selectors](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html).

Comment: but how can I save order

Comment: @Mina, It should keep the order without doing anything. ie. doing `System.out.println(inputs)` will print them in the same order they were in the HTML. Your problem could be that your `listID` does not conserve the order (Is it an ArrayList ?), but I would need to see more code.

Comment: I try with gmail signup form it miss with some inputs , do you know why ?

Comment: @Mina, Possibly because the page uses JavaScript, and Jsoup does not run JavaScript. Try to turn off JavaScript in your browser, check if it works, and if it does, look at the HTML source. [Web browser's developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), (firefox has it also) are also handy. Gmail signup form is going to be quite hard to scrape manipulate / with Jsoup, as Google has probably taken some precautions to prevent this.

Comment: If you are doing stuff with gmail, you might want to check out the Gmail API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/?hl=en